# React navigation native stack header title not auto hiding when using headerLargeTitle along with custom headerTitle component

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

My Code

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  scrollView: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: '120%',
  },
});

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HeaderTitle({children}: {children: string}) {
  return <Text>{children}</Text>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerLargeTitle: true,
          // headerTitle: HeaderTitle,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I use custom headerTitle not small title to not auto hiding when scrolling down to expand and show large title.

Without using the headerTitle property the default title disappears and large title expands to come into view and disappears on scroll back to top.

With headerTitle the default title doesn't disappear but large title expands to come into view and disappears on scroll back to top.